# How to add padding and new line characters to a char array

Tags: c, string

So I have some code that takes a char array representing a string and converts it to its binary format
However, I need to format it so that there are new line characters at each 32nd character within the array. For example for the string 'abcde', 'abcd' would be one line as each character is 8 bits.
Then the next line would be 'e' and then since e is only 8 bits I would need to add another 24 characters of '0' to represent the null terminator.
So it would have to be

1st line : 32 0's and 1's represnting 'abcd'
2nd line: 8 0's and 1's representing 'e' and then 24 0's

```
///
/**
* Takes a string and converts it to a char array representing
* its binary format
**/
char* stringToBinary(char* s) {
    if(s == NULL) return 0; /* no input string */
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    ascii = malloc(len*8 + 1); // each char is one byte (8 bits) and + 1 at the end for null terminator
    ascii[0] = '\0';
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char ch = s[i];
        for(int j = 7; j >= 0; --j){
            if(ch & (1 << j)) {
                strcat(ascii,"1");
            } else {
                strcat(ascii,"0");
            }
        }
    }
    return ascii;
}   
///
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, check if `i` is a multiple of `4`, and insert a newline in the output string before writing the bits. The exception is when `i == 0`, since that's the beginning of the string.

When allocating the string, you need to calculate how many newlines will be in it, and also account for the extra `0` bits at the end.

I've also changed the loop that appends the bits to the string so it just assigns directly to the array index, rather than using `strcat()`. `strcat()` has to search the string every time to find the null terminator.

```
char* stringToBinary(char* s) {
    if(s == NULL) return 0; /* no input string */
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    int newlines = len / 4;
    int bits = len * 8;
    if (len % 4 != 0) {
        newlines++; // Need another newline after the excess characters
        bits += 32 - 8 * (len % 4); // round up to next multiple of 32 bits
    }

    ascii = malloc(bits + newlines + 1); // each char is one byte (8 bits) and + 1 at the end for null terminator
    int ascii_index = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char ch = s[i];
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0) {
            ascii[ascii_index++] = '\n';
        }
        for(int j = 7; j >= 0; --j){
            if(ch & (1 << j)) {
                ascii[ascii_index++] = '1';
            } else {
                ascii[ascii_index++] = '0';
            }
        }
    }
    // Add remaining 0 bits
    for (ascii_index < bits + newlines - 1; ascii_index++) {
        ascii[ascii_index++] = '0';
    }
    // Add final newline and null terminator
    ascii[ascii_index++] = '\n';
    ascii[ascii_index] = '\0';

    return ascii;
}
```